# Scrolling in viewflipper

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, viewflipper

This is one of the intermediate screens in the app.
I'm using a `viewflipper`.

[image: screen shot]

I'm setting this view using `vf.setDisplayedChild(9);` where `vf` is `ViewFlipper` object.

Referring to above screen-shot, if I reach upto country field (which I'm checking through `isFocused()`), **the whole view should scroll by some pixels (equal to keyboard height)**.

If I hadn't used `viewflipper`, then I would have tried something like `scrollTo(x, y)`.
But how do I scroll in `viewflipper`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place a ScrollView as the view inside of the ViewFlipper.

The only problem I think you may still run into is that the keyboard should automatically shift things up (in my experience it doesn't function properly while in fullscreen though).  I'd try displaying that screen without the fullscreen enabled and you may find that your behavior is handled automatically.

Comment: by **fullscreen** mode, u mean without using title/status bar na?

Comment: Right, so having the notification bar/status bar visible helped me out when I had issues with the keyboard hiding items.

Comment: But my requirements forces me to use fullscreen. It's getting scrolled, but by very less margin i.e. fields below `country` are not visible :(

Comment: I have `scrollview` inside `linearlayout`. I'm calling `scrollTo()` on `scrollview`, but its not working.

Comment: You need to add the height of the keyboard as blank space below your layout to have the ability to scroll down that far.  The bottom of your scrollview will be underneath the keyboard.

Comment: How did you add blank space if you don't mind me asking?  I would generally just create a FrameLayout with the height needed (width being fill/match parent) and add that to your layout nested inside of the ScrollView so that it extends the space below the last field/button